# 連連 Trying to understand the double word (叠词 or 叠字) usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

In another answer someone helped me understand the meaning of:

今年一定是好事連連

At that time, I was having trouble getting the context of 連連. But then I saw both 好事連連 (good fortune) and 好运连连 (Good Luck).

When I saw these at first I thought of idioms. When double words are put together, is there always a special meaning? Are there any rules to using double words?

Comment: What you called "double words" is called *reduplication* and is 叠词 or 叠字 in Chinese. 叠 means duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

连连 is an *adverb*.

**ABC**

> 1 repeatedly; again and again; one after another
>
> 他连连摇头。
>
> Tā liánlián yáotóu.
>
> He shook his head repeatedly.
>
> 2 slowly; quietly

**A Chinese English Dictionary**

> repeatedly; again and again
>
> 连连点头
>
> Liánlián diǎntóu
>
> nod again and again (to show agreement, etc.)
>
> 演出结束, 观众连连叫好。
>
> Yǎnchū jiéshù, guānzhòng liánlián jiàohǎo.
>
> At the end of the performance, the audience applauded again and again.

**Oxford**

> over and over again
>
> 连连称好
>
> keep praising
>
> 连连得手
>
> make it again and again

Not all 叠词 are the same, `匆匆` for example is an adjective - `潺潺` is ONOMATOPOEIA - there is no rule for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

> When I saw these at first I thought of idioms. When double words are put together, is there always a special meaning? Are there any rules to using double words?

As a complementary to @user3306356 's answer,
there are some variations of 叠词 (I couldn't cover all of them, but I will list out some for your reference :) )

### 1. Verb

The syntax would be `AA(n.)`, for example:

`吃吃東西` : Eat something

`畫畫圖畫` : Draw something

### 2. Adjective （BAA）

Usually in a form of `(n.)aa` or `(adj.)aa`

Let's consider `紅彤彤` and `白雪雪`

`紅` has the meaning of RED, however 彤 in `紅彤彤` refers to 丹砂 (a red-color ink), which decorates the adjective `紅(RED)` itself.

For `白雪雪`, 雪 means `snow`, which gives `白雪雪` a meaning of "Snowy white".

There are more than one way to describe a single colour in different context, such as 白茫茫,白皙晢,白花花,白蒼蒼,白皚皚 etc.

### 3. Adjective/Adverb （AA / AABB）

We can consider words in form of AA / AABB as 疊詞 as well,

For example, 重重疊疊 (Piles over piles) and 彎彎曲曲 (Curvy, in twist and turns)

### 4. Adjective/Adverb （ABAB / ABAC）

In Chinese language, we also consider the form ABAB and ABAC as 疊詞.

Such as `百發百中`, `自由自在`, however most of them are idioms. We often use double words to emphasize the story itself.

### 5. Onomatopoeia

Sometimes, 疊詞 are just used as onomatopoeia (word that phonetically imitates the sound itself)

`潺潺`, pronounced as 'san san', which imitates the sound of flowing water.
`淙淙`, reads 'cong cong' also refers to the sound of water

### Extra

There is a famous poem《聲聲慢》by 李清照(Li Qingzhao), a poet from Song dynasty which starts with 14 words of 疊詞, is a masterpeice of double words.

> 尋尋覓覓， 冷冷清清， 淒淒慘慘戚戚

Some people tried to translate the lines into English:

> 尋尋覓覓， I seek in vain, I search in vain;
>
> 冷冷清清， Chilled to the bone, all alone;
>
> 淒淒慘慘戚戚。 In pain, in tears, unconsolable.

### Finally, my answer

So, where does `好事連連` fall?

`好事` means "Good things",

`連連` means "Again and again" or simply "repeatedly"

It's in a (n.)AA format, which means literally "Good things happens repeatedly" (It's really a good fortune).